# boto3 file_upload does it check if file exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3

I was looking through the boto3 documentation and could not find if it natively supports a check to see if the file already exists in s3 and if not do not try and re-upload.

Here's what I have working:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket = 'bucketName'
s3_folder = 'folder1234/'
temp_log_dir = "tempLogs/"


s3_client.upload_file(temp_log_dir + file_name, s3_bucket, s3_folder + file_name)
```

What I'm noticing is that if the file exits in S3 already , the .upload_file() from boto3 still transfers the file. I did this check by looking at iftop.

Is there some arg i'm missing to disable "auto overwrite if file exists"?

Thanks

**edit** trying the head method

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
file_name = 'somelogfile.gz'

try:
    s3.Object(s3_bucket+ s3_folder+s3_filename).load()
    print 'success'
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    print e
```

Comment: You are not missing anything you will need to explicitly check to see if the key exists, e.g. `s3_client.head_object('<bucket>', '<keyname>')` this just gets the metadata so should be relatively lightweight.

Comment: So I would put ^ into an if /else first and if it returns a bool (I assume) then continue download.  is keyname = filename? Thx

Comment: You would need to put it in a `try: except:` block because it will raise a `ClientError` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: ill edit the ask. I tried but i'm coming up with this error :     `"%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)`

Comment: Sorry you need `s3_client.head_object(Bucket='<bucket>', Key='<keyname>')`. The alternative is to use the service resource interface, then you could do `s3.Object(<bucket>, <key).load()`

Comment: Thanks check out my latest edit. It seems tow work correctly. But I wanted to see what code it returned since it only returns a bad code if the file doesnt exist ie (403). on my try statement how do I get it to print a "200" for example. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can't get `200` success code because the `botocore` module handles it. You can only get error codes.

Comment: I made a separate question about error handling using your function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000932/capture-clienterror-to-file-python  I'm not sure why my error isn't being captured, can you tell what I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can test the existence of an object using `s3_client.head_object()` or `s3_service.Object().load()`:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def check(s3_client, bucket, key):
    try:
        s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    except ClientError as e:
        return int(e.response['Error']['Code']) != 404
    return True

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
print(check(s3_client, <bucket>, <key>))
```

With `s3` service resource this would achieve the same:

```
def check(s3_service, bucket, key):
    try:
        s3_service.Object(bucket, key).load()
    except ClientError as e:
        return int(e.response['Error']['Code']) != 404
    return True

s3_service = boto3.resource(service_name='s3')
print(check(s3_service, <bucket>, <key>))
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to handle this, but it should be noted that there is a race condition with other uploaders, if present.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
key = 'dootdoot.jpg'
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
if len(objs) > 0 and objs[0].key == key:
 print("Exists!")
else:
 print("Doesn't exist")
```