# Checking if a file exist in S3 bucket or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to check if a file exist or not in a S3 bucket. I am currently using boto3 library in python.

I am using below code to check it exist or not -

```
    file_name = 'random_name'
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    result = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=file_name)

    if 'Contents' in result:
        print('Exist')
    else:
        print('Doesn't exist)
```

But the issue with this code is, it checking for prefix - and it misses edge cases where two file can have same prefix.

Example -
I want to check if file 'hello' exist or not in S3 but there is file 'helloworld' then this program would fail.

Looking for a better solution.

Comment: so if `'Contents'` is there, iterate over `for obj in result['Contents']` and check if any `obj['Key'] == file_name`

Answer (score 0):

Compare the keys directly using standard Python string comprehensions.

The answers to this question go further into detail on this [boto3 file_upload does it check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978426/boto3-file-upload-does-it-check-if-file-exists)